# Adding <br/> dynamically between controls asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, newline

I'm listing some controls at my web page dynamically, either I'm adding newline with Label's.

```
Label newLine = new Label();newLine.Text = "<br/>"; myPanel.Controls.Add(newLine);
```

How can I do it in a different way?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

Comment: because i'm newbie here i have to wait for a special time to mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you don't use 
 at all.  Use CSS to display your controls.  display:block on your elements will work just fine.  Less messy!

Comment: I'm using Css either but I did not know that I could do that with Css. Could you write how? Which css code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

**My problem:**
Add a text to a panel indicating a date range. The text should be placed below an hyperlink.

***The CSS solution:***

**A. Create the CSS class (place it on your page or into a CSS file)**

```
.dateRange
{
    display:block;
}
```

**B. Create controls and set the proper CSS class (.CssClass property)**

```
//1. Create the link
LinkButton _btnTitle = new LinkButton();
_btnTitle.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];
_btnTitle.OnClientClick = "history.go(-1); return false;";
_btnTitle.ToolTip = Request.QueryString["name"];
_btnTitle.CssClass = "title";

//2. Add the link to the container
pnlFindTech.Controls.Add(_btnTitle);  

//3. Create the label (text)    
Label lblDate = new Label();
lblDate.Text = " [ From " + txtDateFrom.Text + " To " + txtDateTo.Text + " ] ";
lblDate.CssClass = "dateRange"; //Here is the trick

//4. Add the label to the container
pnlFindTech.Controls.Add(lblDate);
```

**The final output looks like the this:**

[image]

**Sources:**

- [CSS display Property (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
- [Example (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=block)