# Server control behaving oddly

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have a server control that I have written, which generally works fine. However when I add in the highlighted line, it adds in not one but two `<br />` elements, which is not what I am after.

```
mounting=new DropDownLabel();
mounting.ID="mountTypeList";
mounting.Attributes.Add("class", "mounting");
mounting.Values=Configuration.MountTypes.GetConfiguration().Options;
mounting.Enabled=Utilities.UserType == UserType.Admin;
mounting.Value=value.Reference;
td1.Controls.Add(mounting);
**td1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));**
var span=new HtmlGenericControl("span");
span.Attributes.Add("class", "mountDescription");
span.ID="mountDescription";
td1.Controls.Add(span);
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

ETA:

I have resolved the situation by adding the br using jquery, which I am using there anyway. But the behaviour I saw is surely wrong. If I add an element, it should add that element, not twice that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HtmlGenericControl` will generate the with the opening and closing tags `<br>` and `</br>`

instead you could use `new LiteralControl("<br/>")` which should do what you desire.

EDIT

To get around this you will need your own implementation of the `HtmlGenericControl` and extend it for such cases which don't have opening and closing tags associated.

```
public class HtmlGenericSelfClosing : HtmlGenericControl
{
    public HtmlGenericSelfClosing()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public HtmlGenericSelfClosing(string tag)
        : base(tag)
    {
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagLeftChar + this.TagName);
        Attributes.Render(writer);
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd);
    }

    public override ControlCollection Controls
    {
        get { throw new Exception("Self-closing tag cannot have child controls"); }
    }

    public override string InnerHtml
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
        set { throw new Exception("Self-closing tag cannot have inner content"); }
    }

    public override string InnerText
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
        set { throw new Exception("Self-closing tag cannot have inner content"); }
    }
}
```

[Found Here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/aspnetcontrols/a-self-closing-htmlgenericcontrol)

Comment: Nope - this just adds a span with br in it. The generated code does have the right tag, just twice.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem, and your second solution solved it.

Comment: Thanks, `div.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>");` works for me , similar answer in this question too; http://stackoverflow.com/q/3095228/1847645