# add BR between text in dynamically created control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a dynamically created List in asp.net with the following code:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.ID = "liQuestions" + recordcount.ToString();
li.Attributes.Add("role", "Presentation");
ULRouting.Controls.Add(li);

HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
li.Attributes.Add("myCustomIDAtribute", recordcount.ToString());
anchor.InnerText = "Test " + new HtmlGenericControl("br") + "12345";
li.Controls.Add(anchor);
```

I tried to put in a HtmlGenericControl but that doesn't work. How do I add a br inbetween Test and 12345 please?

Comment: Did you try Environment.NewLine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`InnerHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml) property

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.ID = "liQuestions" + recordcount.ToString();
li.Attributes.Add("role", "Presentation");
ULRouting.Controls.Add(li);

HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
li.Attributes.Add("myCustomIDAtribute", recordcount.ToString());
anchor.InnerHtml = "Test <br/> 12345";
li.Controls.Add(anchor);
```

Or, like this:

```
anchor.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Test")); //or new Literal("Test");
anchor.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
anchor.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("12345")); //or new Literal("12345");
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not able to test it myself right now, I believe the first method in [hazzik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002529/add-br-between-text-in-dynamically-created-control#31002717) would work, but I don't think his second method would. The HtmlGenericControl is known to not support self-closing elements, which the [BR element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) is.

The following SO questions have more detail and another possible solution:

[HtmlGenericControl("br") rendering twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493586/htmlgenericcontrolbr-rendering-twice)

[Server control behaving oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526985/server-control-behaving-oddly)

[Adding <br/> dynamically between controls asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095228/adding-br-dynamically-between-controls-asp-net#3095236)

Comment: @LegalizeIt Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I would've left my critique of hazzik's answer as a comment below it, but as you pointed out, I didn't have enough reputation to do so. I didn't realize it would be better to put it as a comment on my own answer, so I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @LegalizeIt I do think the answer(s) to the related SO questions I linked to provide an answer to the question. I know that the best practice is to put a summary of the solution that is linked to in the answer itself, but I thought that only applied to external links, not links within SO/SE.